# Image URLs not redirecting properly

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I recently migrated my site from http to https. I have set up 301 redirects using htaccess. Everything works fine except the image url. The indexed images in Google has the old urls. when I click the links, they still load in http version. I don't know what is causing the problem. To your reference I'm attaching the current htaccess code here.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank you

Comment: It may help to use something like WP DB Migrate which will go through all of your permalinks (including media permalinks) and update them. Perhaps something like Yoast SEO is causing your canonical image URLs to be at the http version. Could be many things depending on whether you're using a CDN and what plugins you're running.

Comment: Try to install **SSL Insecure Content Fixer**.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found the problem that is causing this issue. It was the htaccess file that is placed inside the uploads folder. After removing the file, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: sure it's not a "cache"?